# installing extensions from vscode shell generate fatal errors

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am encountering an error when trying to install extensions from vscode on Windows 10 x64.

For instance, when I start up vscode, in the bottom right notification area, I see "Analysis Tools Missing". Clicking on this generates an info bar "Some Go analysis tools are missing from your GOPATH. Would you like to install them?"

Hitting the install button generates errors:

> Installing 1 tool   gotests
>
> Installing github.com/cweill/gotests/... FAILED
>
> 1 tools failed to install.
>
> gotests: Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v
>   github.com/cweill/gotests/... github.com/cweill/gotests (download)
>
> cd C:\Users\jchat\Documents\Projects\go\src\github.com\cweill\gotests;
>
> git submodule update --init --recursive
>
> fatal: 'submodule' appears to be a git command, but we were not able to execute it. Maybe git-submodule is broken?
>
> package github.com/cweill/gotests: exit
>   status 128
>
> ...

I can execute the command `go get -u -v github.com/cweill/gotests/` successfully from Git Bash outside of vscode

Is there some configuration I am missing to get this working seamlessly?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running `go get -u -v github.com/cweill/gotests/...` ?
Don't forget the `...` at the end. The `...` (ellipsis) tells `go get` to also fetch the package's sub-packages and its dependencies.

Do you have the `$GOPATH/src/github.com/cweill/gotests` folder? If yes, you can try deleting it.

Comment: Yes, I can run that successfully. The error seems to only occur when run from vscode